# manual certificate authentication for IMAPS

Tags: ssl-certificate, authentication, openssl, imap, x509

I'm running an IMAPS service and users are authenticated with an X.509 certificate.
It works fine using Thunderbird. But how I can connect to the IMAPS service manually using openssl? I use the same certificate with `openssl s_client` than in Thunderbird, but I'm not authenticated.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect $myimapsserver:993 -key my.key -cert my.crt -quiet 
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = $myimapsserver
verify return:1
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE AUTH=PLAIN ACL ACL2=UNION AUTH=EXTERNAL ENABLE UTF8=ACCEPT] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2019 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.
```

Comment: Does your cert need any intermediate cert(s), commonly called 'chain' cert(s), to be validated? If it's from a public CA like Digicert it always does; if it's from a smaller-scope CA like your corporation's headquarters or a city government, it usually does but maybe not.

Comment: I don't need any intermediate cert and the X.509 is validated, but my courier-imap does not authenticate myself if I try to use openssl but the user is authenticated using Thunderbird with the same cert. I guess I have to set a command or an openssl s_client option to authenticate with the X.509 against the imapd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication is possible with the following IMAP command

```
1 AUTHENTICATE EXTERNAL bWljaGE=
```

And then the IMAP servers responded with

```
1 OK LOGIN Ok.
```

The parameter is the base64 encoded username which has to be in the used client X.509 certificate, too.

Comment: it was found via https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=286581

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).